# Proving Weak Law of Large numbers for truncated variables.

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand Dr. Tao's proof of the weak law of large numbers variables with non-finite second moments. In particular the portion where the method of moments tail lemma allows us to conclude From the first moment tail bound (Lemma 1), we know that $(\overline{X_{\geq N}})_n = O(\varepsilon)$ with probability $1 - O(\varepsilon)$. From the second moment tail bound (Lemma 2) and (6), we know that $(\overline{X_{< N}})_n = {\Bbb E} X_{<N} + O(\varepsilon) = {\Bbb E} X + O(\varepsilon)$ with probability $1-O(\varepsilon)$. Any help is appreciated. The part I dont understand is how one can conclude that From the first moment tail bound (Lemma 1), we know that $(\overline{X_{\geq N}})_n = O(\varepsilon)$ with probability $1 - O(\varepsilon)$
[Dr.Tao Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9FNr.png)

Comment: What is your question? You have to say what you didn't understand, else the best one could do is give the proof to you. You list the result you struggled with, but not what part of it you don't understand